# How to use event bubbling in Flex

Tags: apache-flex, events, event-bubbling

Hi 
Actually I wanted to know what is bubbling event and how to make use of it. Also, what is the concept of capturing, targeting and bubbling too?  If any one knows or could give any sample piece of code for explanation that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm confused... why do you think you need to use event bubbling if you don't know what it is? (Maybe this is a homework question?)

Answer (score 2):

[Here's another link](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html) to an Adobe tutorial, recommended by James Ward.

Answer (score 0):

What eactly is your problem?

In short, event bubbling pretty much does what the word says: when clicking on a button that "click event" can be listened to at the button but it also bubbles up in the container stack.

Pretty good docs can be found here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=events_08.html

---

If this helped, please vote or mark answer as correct. THX